# using custom objects in webservices in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a custom object which needs to be sent to a queue as a message . I am using a web service to fetch the request from a website , build the object and send the object as a request to the queue. On debugging the webservice , the object instance does not save the assigned values Eg:

```
Student  cls = new Student();
cls.FirstName="aa";
```

On viewing the attribute cls.FirstName, I see the value aa not being assigned. This object is sent to the queue and there I get an Object Reference Error . It is because the object does not have any value. Kindly let me know a proper approach of working with objects inside a webservice in asp.net. Framework: 4.0.

Comment: can you provide the model that you are using???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no differences between web-services and other section in case of using objects. I am giving you a sample Example...
This is a sample model:

```
public class Student
{
    public string firstName { set; get; }
    public string LastName { set; get; }
}
```

The following is the controller code:

```
Student data = new Student();
data.firstName = "some text";
```